# The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<ChangePasswordActivity>) is undefined

Tags: java, android

Hi have error The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class) is undefined, I'm created the Util class in that class create popup layout in that layout screen logout, chanage password like created textview that text view onClick i have to call the another activity. that time its showing this error.

```
public class Util {


public static void initPopWindow(Activity a, Button button)
{
    final Context context = a;  
    // popupWindow
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
 // popupWindow
    contentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);           
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(contentView, 340, 249, true);
    contentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(button, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 2, 127);



 change_passwrod_activity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            startActivity((new Intent(this, ChangePasswordActivity.class)));

        }
    });
}

}




main Activity call 
public void onSetting(View v) {
 Util.initPopWindow(this, menubutton)
 }
```

Comment: Change this

    
    startActivity((new Intent(this, ChangePasswordActivity.class)))
    // your this here is not a valid context. 

to

     
    startActivity((new Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity.class)))

Comment: This title made me laugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally **this** keyword is pointing to the current class, here your current class is **Util.java**.

`Use activity **context** instead of **this**, because Intent need reference of activity class. It will not accept any other class reference`.

```
startActivity((new Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity.class)));
```

Comment: I have replace my code like startActivity((new Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity.class))); But again this error is coming. The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: 'context.startActivity((new Intent(context,ChangePasswordActivity.class)));' this is work correctly.

Comment: Yes, startActivity() is Activity's method. You need context to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.startActivity((new Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity.class)));
```

Comment: I have replace my code like startActivity((new Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity.class))); But again this error is coming. The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} –

Comment: make your activity 'a' object final and use it there. 

startActivity((new Intent(a, ChangePasswordActivity.class)));

Comment: " context.startActivity((new Intent(context,ChangePasswordActivity.class))); " this is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
change_passwrod_activity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ChangePasswordActivity.class));
    }

});
```

startActivity() is a method within Context, and not within your OnClickListener or Util class.